# How to modify view of sub-directories inside a directory?

Tags: catalina, folders, folder-action, directory-utility

Trying to modify the view of a directroy, I prefer this view:

[image]

But I hate the right part where we see the info on each app. 
Is it possible to modify it to be on default like this (without the information part on the right):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Go to Finder > View > Hide Preview ;)

(Still new to Mac OS)